# Открытие окна через menubar

Tags: python, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, menubar, qaction

Пытаюсь реализовать открытие **`2-го`** окна при нажатии на кнопку в `menubar`, но что-то идёт не так.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QAction, QWidget

lst = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        about = QAction('&О программе', self)

        menu = self.menuBar()
        cpravka = menu.addMenu('&Справка')
        cpravka.self.addAction(about)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('MainWindow')

        self.init_handlers()

    def init_handlers(self):  # обработка открытия 2 окна
        self.about.clicked.connect(self.show_window_2)

    def show_window_2(self):  # открытие 2  окна
        self.w2 = Window2()
        self.w2.show()


class Window2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window2, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Window2')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QAction, QWidget


class Window2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window2, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Window2')
        

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('MainWindow')
        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        about = QAction('&О программе', self)

        menu = self.menuBar()
        
        cpravka = menu.addMenu('&Справка')                     # +++
        self.newAction = cpravka.addAction("О программе")      # +++
        cpravka.triggered.connect(self.show_window_2)          # +++ triggered !!!

    def show_window_2(self, action):  # открытие 2  окна
        if action == self.newAction:
            self.w2 = Window2()
            self.w2.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]